# How to delete some column based on the column headings of a csv file in R?

Tags: r

1. I have loaded a csv file to R.
2. There are 10 columns in the file.
3. I want to save the 1st 3rd and 5th column to a new file.  What is the command line to delete other columns?
4. I want to save the new table, what is the command line should be used?

Comment: R comes with *six manuals*.  One is a general introduction explaining point three about indexing.  Another one is on data import/export and covers point four.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

First, I'll answer your question. If `d` is your data frame loaded from your file, then:

```
d_subset = d[,c(1,3,5)]
write.csv(d_subset, file="file.csv")
```

Second, I'll give you some advice. Read the documentation or buy a good R book. You can even download [An introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) for free. Many of the questions you are asking are very basic. While most people are happy to handle the odd basic question, asking three or four a day really isn't sustainable.

Comment: +1 for _While most people are happy to handle the odd basic question, asking three or four a day really isn't sustainable._