# R: How to extract the search results from web database to R data.frame?

Tags: database, r, extract

(1) I have a list of protein' names.

(2) I want to search a web database for the biological function of these proteins.

(3) I know if the protein's name is in the database, the information such as "location" and "bioactivity" can be found.

(4) Can I do it auotomatically to extract those information to R's data.frame?

(5) If I cannot do it with R, what is the best way to do this automatically?

Many thanks,

Catherine

Comment: This is not a programming question. You're basically asking someone to do your job--like you did with this question: [how to delete some column based on the column headings of a csv file in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5568397/271616)

Answer (score 1):

RCurl is the package you want, as it can be used to scrape the web. Download it, install it, require() it and read the manual and you should be able to do what you want.

Disclaimer: I have not used the package myself, but its the answer to many webscraping questions on R-help.